# Camel rest dsl json contains escape sequence

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel, escaping

I need help with Camel. I prepared some rest service, but I have small problem with response. My response contains escape sequence before ". Could anyone help me with this problem?

My configuration:

```
restConfiguration().port("{{rest_port}}").component("jetty").host("localhost").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

rest("/login").post().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).produces("application/json").consumes("application/json").to("direct:login-rest");

from("direct:login-rest")
        .choice()
        .when(simple("${body[username]} == '{{rest_user}}' and ${body[password]} == '{{rest_password}}'"))
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        String response = new JSONObject().put("Success", true).put("Errors", "").put("Result", new JSONObject().put("token", CURRENT_TOKEN).put("account", new JSONObject().put("guid", "t123123-31231"))).toString(0);
                        exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
                        exchange.getOut().setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
                    }
                })
                .log("AFTER Processor ${body}")
            .otherwise()
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(403));
```

Route:

```
<route id="login" streamCache="true">
    <from uri="direct:login"/>
    <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD">
        <constant>POST</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setBody>
        <simple>
            { "username": "{{rest_user}}", "password": "{{rest_password}}"}
        </simple>
    </setBody>
    <to uri="http4:localhost:{{rest_port}}/login"/>

    <log message="====== ${body}"/>
</route>
```

Logs:

```
2018-02-21 13:48:48,950 [tp1100560861-38] INFO  route3 - AFTER Processor {"Errors":"","Success":true,"Result":{"account":{"guid":"XXX-XXX"},"token":"c86d2900-2754-48ba-bd8d-84ce4338f362"}}

2018-02-21 13:48:48,954 [0 - timer://foo] INFO  login - ====== "{\"Errors\":\"\",\"Success\":true,\"Result\":{\"account\":{\"guid\":\"XXX-XXX\"},\"token\":\"c86d2900-2754-48ba-bd8d-84ce4338f362\"}}"
```

Comment: My Camel version: 2.16.5

Comment: Most likely because of how your json is being serialized. Check the API to see if you can remove this via some parameter.  Its not to do with Camel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add line in Processor:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
```

This is workaround.

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* is that it's due to the `toString` at the end of this line:

```
String response = new JSONObject().put("Success", true).put("Errors", "").put("Result", new JSONObject().put("token", CURRENT_TOKEN).put("account", new JSONObject().put("guid", "t123123-31231"))).toString(0);
```

My reasoning: `restConfiguration` says that it will return JSON.  You construct a `JSONObject` but then turn it to a string, so the route thinks you want to return a string, not an object, so escapes all the quotes to make it a valid JSON string.

Try removing `toString` and see how you get on.

And I won't even comment on how questionable an idea it to roll your own security ;-)

Comment: Nope, after removed toString - didn't print any body.