# Escape Sequence in Camel restlet / rest dsl

Tags: rest, apache-camel, dsl, restlet, jbossfuse

Camel Route -

```
rest("/servicenow").post("/{operation}").consumes("application/json").type(Model.class).produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).to("direct:servicenow");
from("direct:servicenow")
    .setHeader("operationSelector", simple("${header.operation}"))
    .process(new PreProcessor())
    .recipientList().simple("servicenow://${header.instance}?userName=${header.name}&password=${header.password}&apiUrl=${header.apiUrl}")
    .process(new PostProcessor());
```

and PostProcessor Class -

```
    Object msg = exchange.getIn().getBody();
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setLenient();
Gson gson = builder.create();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(msg);
JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
if (element.isJsonArray()) {
    JsonArray array = (JsonArray) element;
    result.add("result", array);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
    exchange.getOut().setBody(result.toString());
} else {
    result.add("result", element);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
    exchange.getOut().setBody(result.toString());
}
```

Example result contains escape sequences in the JSON Array/Object while returning to the Client

```
"{\"result\":[{\"parent\":\"\",\"made_sla\":\"true\",\"caused_by\":\"\"
```

Please do help to modify in the restlet configuration if required so I get response without escape sequence in JSON response.

Comment: instead of `result.toString`, just use result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camel rest dsl json contains escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906914/camel-rest-dsl-json-contains-escape-sequence)

Comment: Hi Kiran, just result doesnt work. Response - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asString"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)

Comment: Try setting `bindingMode=off` (operation attribute) if you do your own marshalling/unmarshalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this line :

```
JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
```

Use this prefered answer :

```
Map<DataType,DataType> result = new HashMap<DataType,DataType>();
result.put("result", array);
exchange.getOut().setBody(result);
```

The restlet will bind the map object to a jsonObject.